# Laravel controller: Iterating a foreach from api body to store in a database

Tags: foreach, controller, laravel-5.3

Hello i am trying to fetch a body from an api iterate it and save all of them in the database, but i got to do it using the foreach and only the first element from response saves into the database instead of all. please i'll would need someone to guide me through the process as my code is below for checkup. Thank you.

```
    $response = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

    // dd($response);

    foreach ($response['bundles'] as $bundle) {
        $store = new IrechargePowerService;

        $store->name = $bundle['description'];
        $store->code = $bundle['code'];
        $store->description = $bundle['description'];

        $store->save();

        dd('done');
    }
```

Comment: you are using dd('done') , just remove it .

Comment: thank you it worked

Answer (score 0):

Put your `dd('done');` under the last curly bracket, outside of foreach loop, like this:

```
    $response = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

    // dd($response);

    foreach ($response['bundles'] as $bundle) {
        $store = new IrechargePowerService;

        $store->name = $bundle['description'];
        $store->code = $bundle['code'];
        $store->description = $bundle['description'];

        $store->save();

    }

    dd('done');
```